# Backend design - handling single resources and multiple resources, or just handle multiple?

Tags: node.js, api, backend

When it comes to designing your backend, imagine you have a resource called cats and it has 2 endpoints; one is used to retrieve a single cat by the id, e.g.

```
function getCat (catId) {
  // get cat by DB call using id
}
```

The other is used to retrieve multiple cats by passing in an array of cat ids, e.g.

```
function getCats (catIds) {
  // get cats by DB call using multiple ids
}
```

What is considered best practice for handling this sort of scenario? Would you maintain both endpoints, or simply omit the single getCat endpoint and pass in an array of 1 item if you need to retrieve a single record? My preference is the latter but I've not seen this implemented in many real-life applications and can't see any articles on the topic.

Comment: Usually your `getCats` would expect more arguments for more sophisticated search criteria. Thus, this one, specific and often used, that allows to find one just by id, is often implemented separately.

Comment: getCat(id) vs getCats(catIds): If getCat endpoint is more frequently reached compared to getCats, it is better to have 2 separate endpoints.